# mod rewrite url with two url parameters

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this url:

```
http://localhost/listing-video.php?q=php+course+online&page=1
```

I need change it in this way:

```
http://localhost/php-course-online/1
```

I added in my .htaccess this code without success:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)?$ listing-video.php?q=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Any help it's really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex doesn't look correct.

Try this rule:

```
# replace - by +
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-(.*)$ $1\+$2 [L]

# rewrite to /listing-video.php
RewriteRule ^videosearchengine/([^/-]+)/([^/-]+)/?$ listing-video.php?q=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA,NE]
```

This will rewrite to: `/listing-video.php?q=php+course+online&page=1`

Comment: Is it placed in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`?

Comment: yes in DOCUMENT_ROOT. I removed a slash before listing-video.php
RewriteRule ^([^/-]+)/([^/-]+)/?$ listing-video.php?q=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA,NE] and I get php error:
atal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Comment: That error is from your php code. I suggest first your do `print_r($_GET)` to se what values you get there.

Comment: ok, I resolved php error, with your code, url works only so: videosearchengine/php+course+online/1 but I need so:
videosearchengine/php-course-online/1

Comment: incredible, now Im getting this strange redirect http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/videosearchengine/php+course-online/1

Comment: I try with hosting online, because probarly localhost its not configured correctly. I dont know because I continue to get redirect to http://localhost/listing+video.php?q=php+course+online&page=1

Comment: ok let's go back to your original requirements. Q1. What URL do you want to enter in browser? Q2. What URL do you want it to be rewritten to?

Comment: this is original url:
http://localhost/videosearchengine/listing-video.php?q=php+course+online&page=1
thi is URL that I want:
http://localhost/videosearchengine/php-course-online/1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42526/discussion-between-anubhava-and-vincenzo-lo-palo)